# Bitcoin blockchain rookie question: how is nonce (the secret number added to each block) generated?

Tags: blockchain, bitcoin

My understanding is that bitcoin minors are all essentially searching for a secret number, which is added to each block of transactions to make the guessing work more difficult. Once plugged into a hash function, the block and the secret number together generate the correct hash, and whoever finds the correct hash gets rewarded.

My question is: where does this secret number come from? Who gets to decide it?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it isn't about programming. It may be on topic on the [Bitcoin](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/) site, but make sure to read through their help center first.

Answer (score 0):

An algorithm of Bitcoin protocol generates this "secret" hash number, depending on [difficulty](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/block/00000000000000000004b2d8909041ea8c0bd224b7cfa6c03d202fc7682eb93d) parameter. Look at info about block 700670. Miners tried to guess this number (with 19 leading zeros) to get a reward and record a "legitimate" transaction in the ledger.

```
00000000000000000004b2d8909041ea8c0bd224b7cfa6c03d202fc7682eb93d
```

Comment: I understand that nonce (or rather the hash of it + block) is what miners are searching for. What I don't understand is how is nonce kept unknown to everyone, including the creater? If someone built this system and created a protocol, couldn't this person backtrack what each nonce is?

Comment: Due to its (nonce's) randomization's nature.

Comment: You can't predict what number the random number generator will generate. In the same way, you cannot predict what the `nonce` will be.

Comment: @dyxdyx Combinatioin of previous block hash and nonce results next block hash. The miner must find such a nonce, that the resulting hash will have 19 leading zeros. This is pure luck, due to the "quality" of the SHA-256 algorithm. First of all, there is a mathematical proof, that if you take SHA-256 hash with 19 leading zero, you can't calculate or at least approximate the original value and the nonce. As an example, imagine that the hacker stole the database with SHA-256 password hashes. He can't "guess" the original value of the password, even if he knows password hash.

Comment: @dyxdyx The same with bitcoin nonce. Both miners and the hackers might need months to "guess" the correct nonce or original password. You would need to spend such a large amount of CPU energy that the operation of "guessing" the password or mining the bitcoin becomes very expensive for one miner and for one hacker. Of course, if 1 million hackers would unite and would try to guess your original password from SHA-256 hash at the same time, one of them would eventually succeed. The same is true for miners. If you want to become successful in mining unite with other miners and share the profit :)

Answer (score 0):

This "secret number", or nonce, is absolutely random.
You can choose any nonce you like, with any digits.
Depending on the difficulty of the correct hash requirements, you might need quintillions of attempts to finally guess the correct hash.

There is a mathematical proof that any nonce you try is not better than any other. Otherwise SHA-256 hash algorithm would be easy to break. So you just need enough CPU power to try as much numbers as possible.

P.S. Of course, if you would try milliard numbers, each of them with milliard digits, then your algorithm would be too slow, I guess.

So if I would be a miner, I would start with 0 and then try any possible number in a natural sequence. The less digits the number has, the faster the algorithm should be.

Answer (score 0):

it's not a secret number

it's a 256 bit SHA256 output represented as a 64 char hash digest

it's any 64 char hash value that starts with the specified quantity of zeros, for example if the bitcoin algorithm specifies that it must start with eight zeros then a sha256 hash digest of 00000000a16506ee98e8de04e91638d614546a116580c7d81d5807616cba8096 will mine the block, any hash digest that starts with eight or more zeros will mine the block.

there are multiple correct answers, first to guess a correct answer mines the block, gets the reward.

Answer (score 0):

Combination of the **previous block hash** and the **nonce** results the **next block hash**. The miner must find such a **nonce**, that the resulting hash will have 19 leading zeros. This is pure luck, due to the quality of the **SHA-256** algorithm. The more leading zeros resulting hash must have, the harder it is to find the nonce. (because there are much less numbers with 19 leading zeros, than there are numbers with 10 leading zeros, for example)

First of all, there is a mathematical proof, that if you know **SHA-256** hash with 19 leading zeros and the **previous block hash**, then you can't calculate or at least approximate the **nonce**. You can only "**guess**" it, by trying absolutely random numbers of any kind. Even if you know how SHA-256 algorithm is implemented (this is absolutely public information, you can easily find it), this will not help you at all. **SHA-256** is actually designed in such a way that you will not be able to revert **original value**, even if you know the **resulting hash**. You can actually mathematically prove that there is no formula to find or even approximate the **original value**. Or you can just trust the mathematicians, who proved it. If you can trust these mathematicians, or prove it yourself, or just read and understand the proof in the scientific papers or books, then you can automatically trust in **bitcoin mathematics**.

In the **bitcoin** design, which uses **SHA-256** hashing algorithm:

- the r**esulting hash** is a **next block hash**
- the **original value** is a concatenation of the **previous block hash** and the **nonce**
- the **resulting hash** must have **19 leading zeros**
- the **previous block hash** is a known value
- the **nonce** is unknown value, or **X**

As another example, imagine that the hacker stole the database with SHA-256 **password hashe**s. He can't "**guess**" the **original value** of the password, even if he knows the **password hash**.

The same is true with bitcoin **nonce**. Both miners and the hackers might need months to "**guess**" the correct **nonce** or **original password**. (For hacker it is actually much harder to succeed, because there is only one possible "**original password value**", but there are very large amount of numbers with **19 leading zeros**)

In any case, you would need to spend such a large amount of **CPU energy** that the operation of "**guessing**" the password or mining the bitcoin becomes very expensive for one miner and for one hacker. Of course, if 1 million hackers would unite and would try to guess your original password from **SHA-256** hash at the same time (each of them trying different ranges of numbers), then one of them would eventually succeed. The same is true for miners. If you want to become successful in mining, buy expensive hardware, unite with other miners and share the profit :)